# plot a graph with its x-label is month and date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this

```
    2015max  2015min  idxmax  idxmin
01-05    242.0    -54.0   241.0  -127.0
01-26    245.0    -45.0   238.0  -134.0
04-02    298.0    -23.0   280.0   -59.0
04-04    288.0     72.0   283.0   -86.0
04-17    281.0     29.0   278.0   -47.0
```

I want to overlay a scatter of the data for any points with its x-lable is a year like "01-01,01-02,01-03..."
I have tried to use

```
idxmin.index = pd.to_datetime(idxmin.index, format='%m-%d',errors='ignore')
```

but it always remind me of the error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

Is there someone has a good idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems in your data are some bad values, so need parameter `error='coerce'` for replace them to `NaT` and then replace `NaT` to some value:

```
print (idxmin)
       2015max  2015min  idxmax  idxmin
01-05    242.0    -54.0   241.0  -127.0
01-26    245.0    -45.0   238.0  -134.0
04-02    298.0    -23.0   280.0   -59.0
04-04    288.0     72.0   283.0   -86.0
04-35    281.0     29.0   278.0   -47.0 <- change last value to bad for testing

idxmin.index = pd.to_datetime(idxmin.index, format='%m-%d',errors='coerce') 
print (idxmin)
            2015max  2015min  idxmax  idxmin
1900-01-05    242.0    -54.0   241.0  -127.0
1900-01-26    245.0    -45.0   238.0  -134.0
1900-04-02    298.0    -23.0   280.0   -59.0
1900-04-04    288.0     72.0   283.0   -86.0
NaT           281.0     29.0   278.0   -47.0

idxmin.index = idxmin.index.fillna(pd.to_datetime('01-01-2000'))
print (idxmin)
            2015max  2015min  idxmax  idxmin
1900-01-05    242.0    -54.0   241.0  -127.0
1900-01-26    245.0    -45.0   238.0  -134.0
1900-04-02    298.0    -23.0   280.0   -59.0
1900-04-04    288.0     72.0   283.0   -86.0
2000-01-01    281.0     29.0   278.0   -47.0
```

You can also check all bad values:

```
print (idxmin.index[pd.isnull(pd.to_datetime(idxmin.index, format='%m-%d',errors='coerce'))])
Index(['04-35'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I want to draw a scatter of the data for any points with its x-lable is a year like "01-01,01-02,01-03..." I wonder why 1900(the year) exist when I want it format just month and date. And how to draw a graph?

Comment: I have found the bad value:   Index(['02-29'], dtype='object')    I think the date is existed acctually. So how can I solve the problem?

Comment: To your first question - If need datetimes, some default years has to be in each dates. You can get `day` and `month` from each date by `idxmin.index = pd.to_datetime(idxmin.index, format='%m-%d',errors='coerce').strftime('%m-%d')`, but it is same as your input. So If need some dates, year are necessary.

Comment: To your second comment - you can replace `NaT` by some value or is possible rename `02-29` to another value - use before converting to datetime `idxmin = idxmin.rename(index={'02-29':'02-28'})`

Comment: Thank you very much! It is very helpful ! I am afraid I have another problem.How can I draw a scatter graph with all year date as the x-axis and  '2015max' as the y-axis? Thank you for your patience~

Comment: If you check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-plot), `scatter` need numbers in both axis. So is possible use e.g. `2015max` vs `idxmax`.  If need years only from index (if understand it correct), is necessary create new column by `idxmin['years'] = idxmin.index.year` and then use `2015max` vs `years`